# Downloading large file using ProcessStartInfo not continue after WaitForExit

Tags: c#, .net, download, large-files, processstartinfo

I use `ProcessStartInfo` to download files. The code is as the following:

```
Process pc = new Process();
pc.StartInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath + "\\" + [exe];
pc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("Download {0}{1}{2} -out {3}{4}{5}", [some arguments]);
pc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
pc.Start();
pc.WaitForExit();
```

But, when trying to install large files (+250 MB), it downloads but doesn't continue after `WaitForExit`.

Comment: It downloads *or* it downloads and the exe finishes?

Comment: "it downloads but doesn't continue after WaitForExit"...  bet ya your mystery downloading exe is still running in the background (check task manager)

Comment: @Trey thanks for reply. So how to solve it by coding ?

Comment: Welll.. that's a problem with the exe you are calling.... that being said, probably just enumerate the running tasks, and then end task that one through code.  Really depends, I used to run into this with acrobat reader, and I always had to end the process manually.